# How to check max of element.scrollTop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

tell me please. How to get the max of refCurrent.scrollTop in this example?
i'm trying to find an analog https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTopMax
for chrome.

```
const SecondTab = () => {

  const refS = useRef(null);
  const [scrollValue, setScrollValue] = useState(0);
  const scrollHandler = (e) => {
    const refCurrent = refS.current;
    setScrollValue(refCurrent.scrollTop);
  };

return (
<div className={Style.title} ref={refS} onScrollCapture={scrollHandler}>
        <strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</strong>, consectetur adipisicing
        elit. Beatae eveniet debitis accusamus praesentium eius voluptas
</div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way id

```
$(document).height() -
$(window).height()
```

Other way around is by defining custom scrollTopMax method which work by subtracting scrollTop with clientHeight

Comment: Muhammad thanks for ur answer. 
But it's for all page. How to calculate for some div?  the content changes, so the div height also changes